# Yii: Retrieving data using Cdbcriteria

Tags: php, yii

I am yiibie. What I am trying to do is to retrieve data from my database, and for that i am using `cDbCriteria`. I want to get the last 4 images from my database table which is named `Event`. and then want to display those 4 images individually. I am using this method but not getting any result, please help me with this.

```
      <?php
 $Criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$Criteria->limit = 4;
$Criteria->order = "image DESC";
$Criteria->select = "id, image";
$Events = Event::model()->findAll($Criteria);
foreach ( (array)$Events as $Event)
{
    $Event[1]=$image1;
    $Event[2]=$image2;
    $Event[3]=$image3;
    $Event[4]=$image4;

}
  ?>
<div class="row">
<h3>Events</h3>
<div class="col-md-3">
<div class="thumbnail">

   <img src="<?php echo $image1  ?>">

<div class="caption">
    <a href="join.php"> <button class="btn btn-primary center-block">Join</button></a>
  </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

findAll() method retrieves an array of ActiveRecords, so you need a foreach loop. Try:

```
foreach ( (array)$Events as $Event)
{
   echo "
      <div class='col-md-3'>
         <div class='thumbnail'>
            <img src='$Event->image' >
            <div class='caption'>
               <a href='join.php'><button class='btn btn-primary center-block'>Join</button></a>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   ";
}
```

Comment: <div class="thumbnail">
    <?php
    foreach ( (array)$Events as $Event)
{
   echo "<img src='$Event->image' >"; 
}
    ?>
<div class="caption">
    <a href="join.php"> <button class="btn btn-primary center-block">Join</button></a>
  </div>
    </div>
i tried it like this but it isn;t showning me image

Comment: please can to edit it in the above code, actually i am not good with these things, i will be thankfull.

Answer (score 0):

```
$Criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$Criteria->limit = 4;
$Criteria->order = "id DESC";
$Criteria->select = "id, image";
$Events= Event::model()->findAll($Criteria);
```

This will gives last 4 records

1st way

```
if(isset($Events[0]))
      echo $Events[0]->image;
if(isset($Events[1]))
      echo $Events[1]->image;
if(isset($Events[2]))
      echo $Events[2]->image;
if(isset($Events[3]))
      echo $Events[3]->image;
```

i am here checking `isset()` because there may b 3 entry.    This is static

2nd way

```
foreach($Events as $event)
   {
      echo $event->image;
   } 

  this is dynamic binding.
```

Comment: i have updated the question please have a look at it.

Comment: foreach also display image individual. that is dynamic. and it is good practice use dynamic binding then static binding

Comment: Thanks @jazz for your answer, i understand the logic but i am unable to display the image, the code is correct as i displayed a name in some other example using the same code. what could be the problem, why it is not showing image?

Comment: i am using the secong way, the dynamic binding.

Comment: @SalikAsad there may b path issue so your image is not displaying. check is it correct path or not. and good dynamic binding is good idea